# Using Play framework 2 with DB2 (AS400 or LUW)

Tags: playframework, db2, playframework-2.0, db2-400

is there anyone who sucessfully used Play framework with IBM DB2 for AS00 or DB2LUW. I was trying to run the Zentasks example against a DB2 db on AS400, but I got this exception:

```
Internal server error, for (GET) [/projects/1/tasks]

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Token <END-OF-STATEMENT> not valid. Valid tokens: AS CL IN LOG OUT DATA COLLECT.                                                                                
Bind values:[null]                                                                                                               
Query was:                                                                                                                       
select count(*) from ( select distinct t0.id c0                                                                                  
from project t0                                                                                                                  
join project_account u1z_ on u1z_.project_id = t0.id                                                                             
join account u1 on u1.email = u1z_.account_email                                                                                 
where u1.email = ?  and t0.id = ? )
```

The above query isn't valid in the DB2 syntax. A valid one would be something like;

```
with qry as ( select distinct t0.id c0                                                                                  
from project t0                                                                                                                  
join project_account u1z_ on u1z_.project_id = t0.id                                                                             
join account u1 on u1.email = u1z_.account_email)  
select count(*) from qry where u1.email = ?  and t0.id = ?
```

Comment: I've not used Play, but I can tell you the problem with that query is that the subquery there doesn't have an identifier, it should be something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ...) A`, the `A` being the missing bit.

Comment: +1 to @bhamby. The proper term for identifier A is _correlation name_. It is required for subqueries in the FROM clause in older DB2 versions.

Comment: I couldn't remember the correct term off the top of my head at the time, and I didn't want to look it up. `:)` Thanks @mustaccio

Comment: @bhamby Good suggestion, thanks. Now the problem is how to tell Play to add this correlation name. :-)